# NEXT13 App Router ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: node.js, next.js, next.js13

I am trying to build a video chat app and have run into an issue when trying to build the app (there are no issues when I run npm run dev). Also please ignore the messy code, promise too refactor once i get past this issue:

This is my page.tsx file:

```
"use client";


const ChatRoom = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch auth token from Firebase
    auth.currentUser
      ?.getIdToken(true)
      .then((token) => {
        setToken(token);

        // ... Existing code using socket
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error("Error fetching the token", error);
      });
  }, [user.uid]);

  const myPeer = new Peer();
  useEffect(() => {
    const myVideo = document.createElement("video");

    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      global.navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: true,
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          setMyStream(stream);
          addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

          myPeer.on("call", (call) => {
            call.answer(stream);
            const video = document.createElement("video");
            call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
              addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
            });
          });

          socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
            connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
          });
        });
    }

    // Listen for incoming messages

    socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId) => {
      if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close();
    });

    myPeer.on("open", (id) => {
      socket.emit("join-room", id, roomId);
    });

    function connectToNewUser(userId: string, stream: MediaStream) {
      const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);

      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });
      call.on("close", () => {
        video.remove();
      });

      peers[userId] = call;
    }

    function addVideoStream(video: HTMLVideoElement, stream: MediaStream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        video.play();
      });
      if (videoGridRef.current) {
        videoGridRef.current?.appendChild(video);
      }
    }
  }, [user.uid]);
  const handleMuteAudio = () => {
    if (myStream) {
      myStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = audioMuted;
      setAudioMuted(!audioMuted);
    }
  };

  const handleMuteVideo = () => {
    if (myStream) {
      myStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = videoMuted;
      setVideoMuted(!videoMuted);
    }
  };
  const handleMessage = () => {
    // Implementation to send a message
    socket.emit("chat-message", currentMessage, roomId);
    setCurrentMessage("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen for incoming messages
    socket.on("chat-message", (message) => {
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    switch (name) {
      case "username":
        setFormData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, username: value }));

        break;
      case "password":
        setFormData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, password: value }));

        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  const handleLogin = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const user = loginWithEmail(formData.username, formData.password);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(`error login in: ${error}`);
      setError(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {!user.uid ? (
        <main className="container px-7 py-10 w-screen h-screen">
          <section className=" flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-full">
            <h1>Display Name</h1>
            <form
              onSubmit={handleLogin}
              className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2"
            >
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="username">Display Name:</label>
                <input
                  id="username"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  className="border-2 border-black rounded p-2 m-1"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <button
                  className=" p-2 border-4 rounded-xl border-black w-44 shadow-lg text-center "
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Login
                </button>
              </div>
              {error && <p>There was an Error Logging in</p>}
            </form>
          </section>
        </main>
      ) : (
        <div className="flex h-screen">
          <div
            ref={videoGridRef}
            className="flex-grow grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 p-4 overflow-auto scrollbar-thin"
          >
            {/* Videos will be appended here */}
          </div>
          <div className="w-1/4 min-w-[200px] h-screen border-l border-gray-300 p-4 overflow-auto scrollbar-thin">
            <div>
              {messages.map((message, index) => (
                <p key={index}>{message}</p>
              ))}

              <input
                type="text"
                value={currentMessage}
                onChange={(e) => setCurrentMessage(e.target.value)}
              />

              <div className="flex gap-1 ">
                {" "}
                <button
                  className="border-black rounded-lg border"
                  onClick={handleMuteAudio}
                >
                  {audioMuted ? "Unmute Audio" : "Mute Audio"}
                </button>
                <button
                  className="border-black rounded-lg border"
                  onClick={handleMuteVideo}
                >
                  {videoMuted ? "Unmute Video" : "Mute Video"}
                </button>
              </div>

              <button onClick={handleMessage}>Send</button>
              <button
                onClick={() => logOut()}
                className="flex justify-center items-center w-fit border-2 p-2 rounded-lg"
              >
                Log Out
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ChatRoom;
```

and this is the Error:

```
next build

- info Loaded env from C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.env.local
- info Creating an optimized production build
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types
- info Collecting page data
[    ] - info Generating static pages (0/10)ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\chunks\500.js:15910:20)
    at Object.84714 (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\chunks\500.js:15859:51)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
    at Module.19337 (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\app\(pages)\room\page.js:425:64)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
    at M (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:46)
    at ma (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:28:324)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:31:63)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at L (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:23:53)

Error occurred prerendering page "/room". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\chunks\500.js:15910:20)
    at Object.84714 (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\chunks\500.js:15859:51)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
    at Module.19337 (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\app\(pages)\room\page.js:425:64)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:43)
    at M (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:46)
    at ma (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:28:324)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:31:63)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at L (C:\Users\Asus\final-project-attempt\templateWebsite\lauren-shower\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:23:53)
[=   ] - info Generating static pages (1/10)(node:16000) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
- info Generating static pages (10/10)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /(pages)/room/page: /room
```

Thanks for the help!!

Code  is marked as to run on the client. not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navigator` object is only available on the client side, so it will not be defined when the page is rendered on the server.

A few ways to fix this error:

- **Use a dynamic import**. This is the recommended approach. To do this, you can use the `import()` function with the `dynamic` keyword. For example:

  `import { navigator } from 'window';`
- **Use a client-only component**. If you only need to use the `navigator` object in a client-only component, you can wrap the component in a `React.Suspense` component with a fallback. For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <MyClientOnlyComponent />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
};
```

- **Use a third-party library**. There are a few third-party libraries that can help you to work around the `navigator` issue in Next.js. One such library is `react-window`.

Comment: Thanks for this!! I found similar comments when I googled, but the code is already in a client component with "use client" and in a useEffect , do I need to move the navigator.gerUserMedia() code block outside of my page.tsx file?

Comment: Actually never mind, I was originally getting the user media from page.tsx, but like you suggested, i need to create a videoPlayer (in my case ChatRoom) client component then import to page.tsx (which has to be a server component)